# How to structure a simple JPA / GenericDAO dynamic web applicaiton

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am just starting to work with JPA.  Based on several tutorials, I have built a simple dynamic web project that includes a GerericDAO as well as a singleton that encapsulates the EntityManagerFactory.

```
public class PersistenceManager {
    private static final PersistenceManager instance = new PersistenceManager();
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;
    public static PersistenceManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    private PersistenceManager() {
    }
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf == null)
            createEntityManagerFactory();
        return emf;
    }
    public void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf != null) {
            emf.close(); emf = null;
        }
    }
    protected void createEntityManagerFactory() {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Fusion");
    }
}



public class GenericJPADAO<ID extends Serializable, T> implements GenericDAO<ID, T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericJPADAO() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (entityManager == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("EntityManager has not been set on DAO before");
        return entityManager;
    }
    public T create(T element) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        if (element == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        try {
            getEntityManager().persist(element); 
            return element;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("create failed");
        }
    }
```

To pull this together in a Transaction method I need something like this (leaving out some of the detail):

```
DAOFactory factory = DAOFactory.instance(DAOFactory.JPA);
ConfigurationDAO dao = factory.getAddressDAO();
dao.setEntityManager(entityManager);
EntityTransaction ut = entityManager.getTransaction();      
try {
    ut.begin();
    dao.create(address);
    ut.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ut.rollback();
}
    finally {
 close??
}
```

I am very new to this, however it seems awkward to be setting the EntityManager in the DAO Class from the Transaction method.  I have previously worked with Hibernate and my DAO classes have been able to retrieve a current Session from a HibernateUtil type class.  I am not sure how to achieve a similar structure with JPA / EntityManager whilst maintaining a Thread safe application?  Maybe my structure is poorly designed - anyway any advice / guidance much appreciated.  I have not been able to find a clear complete example of this.  By the way - I am not using Spring in this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA specification defines a pattern similar to Hibernate's `getCurrentSession()` - the current `EntityManager` is injected into field annotated with `@PersistenceContext`.

However, specification says that support for this pattern should be provided by external environment rather than by JPA providers, therefore you cannot just use it in standalone environment.

In particular, this pattern is supported by Spring Framework and Java EE application servers.

Alternatively, if you cannot use Spring Framework or Java EE application server you can emulate this pattern by storing the current `EntityManager` in `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Ok I have seen reference to ThreadLocal - I will look at this further.  Regarding Spring - I am fairly new to Java and Spring appears (to me) to have a fairly steep learning curve.  I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 - does this make a difference?

Comment: @bugy: If you declare your DAOs as EJBs you should be able to use `@PersistenceContext` at Glassfish - see, for example, http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_persistence_jpa_for